# replacing letters in a word at his reverse sed

Tags: bash, sed

I need to write script in sed that
The program prints the contents of the output file one after replacing all the old word
Three letters of the file - its first in reverse. (1 file contents remains unchanged after
Program)

example:

File F1:

```
hell hi uri ronit dani 
abc def ab abcd 
123456 123ab
```

after this command P8.3 F1 Received the following output:

```
hell hi iru ronit dani 
cba fed ab abcd 
123456 123ab
```

thanks

Comment: Can you try to give a better explanation?

Comment: This sounds like a homework problem. What have you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sed 's/\(\b\)\(\w\)\(\w\)\(\w\)\(\b\)/\1\4\3\2\5/g' input_file
```

Comment: thanks but can you explain me please what is /b and what's g

Comment: @yuval:  `\b` denotes a word boundary, and `g` means to do a global substitution (i.e. don't stop after the first match on the line).